# Can't push/pull from local docker registry

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have created a cluster of Kubernetes, and installed docker for each node.
When I try to pull or push an image to my local registry, using docker `push local_registry_addr:port/image_id`, I get the following response: `Get local_registry_addr:port/v2: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`.

This happens although I got the certificate from the registry server, and add it as a certificate on my docker server. If I try to `wget local_registry_addr:port`, I get `200 OK`.

How can I fix it? Is there anything I need to configure perhaps?

Comment: Did you restarted you docker after adding the certs ? also where did you added the certs?

Comment: @AmanJuneja I added the cert to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, and then I run the command: `sudo update-ca-certificates`. Yes, I did restart the docker after adding the cert and I used the following command: `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`.

Comment: Add certs in /etc/docker/certs.d/local_registry_addr:port/ and restart docker

Comment: @AmanJuneja It did not help, still get the same error. Although I did make it work as I mentioned in my answer, is there anything else that can be done to make it work using the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't suppose to add the port - using `push local_registry_addr/image_id` worked fine.